# Watching ImageMagick and killing when they run too long

Tags: monitoring, imagemagick

I use a program that calls [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s command-line commands. These are supposed to run instantly -- perhaps 1 or 2 seconds. However, lately I've noticed a bunch of them got stuck.

[image: Frozen processes]

I use monit to monitor the server and watch certain things when the memory goes overboard. What would be a good way to watch ImageMagick? I'd like to **kill the processes if they've been alive for 1 minute**. However, I don't want to do a blanket kill all `convert` processes.

What do I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the output of `ps -ef` (or `ps -axf` on BSDish systems) to find processes with a start time (`STIME`) greater than `X`, or you can use `TIME` (CPU seconds used).

---

Implementation of this solution is left as an exercise for the reader, it's relatively simple.  Hints:

- You can do it with a shell script (`for line in top; do ... done`)
- `grep` and `awk` (or `cut`) are your friends
- `STIME` changes format depending on how long the process has been running.
  If we're talking within a 24 hour period you shouldn't have to worry about that, and you can kill any process that doesn't match the expected format for something started <24 hours ago.
- Test your script first (`echo "I want to kill $PID ($line)"`) before you let it really shoot processes in the head!

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks! Will try this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to modify the way ImageMagick is called?  Setting limits with ulimit/limit before execing ImageMagick would allow you to set the CPU seconds and the kernel will take care of it for you.

http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/man.cgi?section=1&topic=limit

Comment: I could, if I add a patch to the [library I'm using](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly). I've asked the guy in charge to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

[BASH FAQ entry #68: "How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)